# python print hashlib.sha256 SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x, bitcoin

I am reading the book "Mastering Bitcoin" (from Andreas M. Antonopoulos, page 193) and wanted to try something myself but got already stuck by the first steps (in Python: 3.3.4):

```
Python 3.3.4 (v3.3.4:7ff62415e426, Feb 10 2014, 18:12:08) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

>>> import hashlib

>>> print hashlib.sha256("I am Satoshi Nakamoto").hexdigest()
File "<stdin>", line 1
    print hashlib.sha256("I am Satoshi Nakamoto").hexdigest()
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

"print" is a function in Python 3, so you need to use braces:

```
print(hashlib.sha256("I am Satoshi Nakamoto".encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())
```

Please note that I am encoding the string, because of a TypeError that occurs otherwise.

Comment: Actually I think you mean `print()` is a function of Python 3. `print` has been around since at least Python 1.4 (circa 1996). In Python 3 `print()` replaced `print`.

Comment: Well, that's what I said, right? "In Python 3 it is a function".

Comment: Definitely correct, but at first glance didn't read that way. I read it more as the "print" statement is a function (only in) Python 3.

Comment: That's a matter of debate, I guess. As far as I know, the function is "print". The braces just denote the application of said function. Try entering "print" in a Python3 REPL, then you'll see.

Comment: I don't need to try it ... I'm just telling you how it read to me. And if you need clarification on `print` vs `print()` then maybe look at what it says: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html and notice how it's used.

Comment: No problem. Would you please mark my answer as correct? Thanks.